# Relative clause - die/sie

Tags: relative-clause

Which one of the two following sentences is correct (if any)?

> Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, die zu verwalten.

or

> Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, sie zu verwalten.

Comment: It's not a relative clause. Both versions are correct but "sie" is way more idiomatic. You need to use "um zu" here. "zu" sounds poetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both original versions are correct, but don't sound "native" to me. I'd state it like:
"Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, der sie für uns verwaltet."

The beginning of the sentence sounds rather informal (everyday spoken language, e.g. chatting with a neighbor), so I'd continue in that mode. Omitting the "um" from the "um zu" clause is more appropriate in a formal tone.

And, to be honest, "um zu" does not really catch the relationship between the search process and the management work - that's why I chose a real relative clause.

As a written-language version (e.g. advertisement), I'd phrase it like this:
"Wir suchen einen Verwalter für unsere zwei neu gekauften Wohnungen."

And then continue "Bei Interesse bitte anrufen unter Tel (012345) 678910." ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate a little oh the difference between "...die zu verwalten" and "...sie zu verwalten". Or, along the lines of your suggestion - "...der sie für uns verwaltet" and "...der die für uns verwaltet".

Answer (score 0):

```
Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, die zu verwalten.
```

Is correct, but you better say:

```
Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, um diese zu verwalten.
```

the "jemanden" wants a descriptinon or a reason: somenone, who...

Edit:

```
Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, um sie zu verwalten.
```

works too.

Comment: I don't see a reason why we should use "diese" and would therefor say that the more straightforward "sie" is the stylistically better choice. Also, the OP-version may be correct but only with Drama-glasses on.

Answer (score 0):

A) "sie" is better than "die" as "die" indicates emotional distance to what is referred to.

B) "diese" is better than "die", as it is a more elegant way of indicating distance here. And it is less ambigious as it is used for referencing words which not directly precede the pronoun.

C) You can omit the "um", but it reads less elegeant and looks strange and makes it harder to get the sense. (It took me minutes to understand that the first sentence is correct, too.) In spoken language it is ok but still a little strange.

My advice:

```
Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, um sie zu verwalten.
Wir haben zwei Wohnungen gekauft, und jetzt suchen wir jemanden, diese zu verwalten.
```

(The second one I would definitely even write it that way.)

The problem with omitting "um" in connection with "die" is, that it leads to ambiguation. In the beginning and moment of hearing it's not clear weahter "Wohnung" or "jemanden" is meant with "die". "diese" without "um" is much more clearer -- as "diese" and "jene" are typically used for referencing nouns mentioned longer ago.

Comment: I disagree that "diese" is better. There is no ambiguity that "diese" could help clear up and I consider using more complex structures if there is no need for it bad style. That's just my opinion of course but I'm sure I'm not the only one who sees it that way.